# How to secure database access in mvc web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a web application in ASP.NET MVC, iOS and Android app using Xamarin that would have a common SQL Server database. I would want to develop a common layer/object that will have functions and methods common to all applications. I am also concerned about database security. I would want understand is there any other way in which this can be achieved.

I planning this roadmap :

1. I will develop web service or WCF services and host on a server, applications will communicate with these services and services will communicate with DB server.
2. If I develop web service or WCF service and host on a server, I want to prevent direct access and attack.
3. Which is better for my applications, web service or wcf service?

Masters please guide me.

Comment: WCF ***is*** web services ..... there's no *web services **or** WCF services* - WCF is *one way* of writing web services.....

Comment: _Access_ - control by authentication and authorization. _Attack_ is broad and you'll be better off using an application firewall ([WAF](https://www.google.com/search?q=web%20application%20firewall%20service)) service than thinking of cobbling one yourself.

Comment: Thanks marc_s and EdSF. I want to know what object(wcf web service or n-tire layers or any other) should I develop to make functions and methods common between SQL database and all my applications ie MVC, android and IOS app. Will it be better to create single common object for all applications or should I create seperate object for all applications. Please guide.